# Accept headers of the clojure.xml/parse call

Tags: clojure

When calling the function `clojure.xml/parse` with an URI Clojure performs a HTTP GET request to fetch the data. However the HTTP request contains the following accept headers:

```
text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

Shouldn't this be `application/xml`?

Comment: This sounds like a bug report, so I think you should direct this question to Clojure's Google group. Also note that `clojure.xml` has other deficiences whose fixing probably won't be prioritised at this time; thus `clojure.contrib.lazy-xml` is probably a better choice. (Not sure if it's free of the particular problem you're describing, thus not posting this as an answer.)

Comment: Ok, I've posted it on the Google group.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `clojure.xml/parse` with a `String` parameter (URI) is similar to this java code:

```
SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse("<your_uri>", <instance of XMLHandler provided by Clojure>);
```

Clojure does not perform a HTTP GET request. It just uses SAX parser as default parser. Sax parser internally creates an instance of `XMLInputSource` and passes it all the way down to `XMLEntityManager`. Class `XMLEntityManager` does all the work related to opening connection and getting your xml (or more like html) document:

```
URL location = new URL(expandedSystemId); 
URLConnection connect = location.openConnection();
... skip ...
stream = connect.getInputStream();
```

If `XmlInputSource` is an instance of `HTTPInputSource`, then `XMLEntityManager` sets up HTTP request properties. However, there is no similar functionality for `XMLInputSource` (which is what we have in case of SAXParser).

I guess you what might help you is changing your SAX parser to some other implementation.